# Best way to password protect a Java console application

Tags: java, hash, cryptography

I am looking for a best-practice or standard method to password protecting a console application. I have researched various methods and would like some feedback on my approach.

I have decided to hash my password using Argon2 so that I only have to store the one-way hash. Everything is working as expected. The question I have is where do I store the hash? Should it be hard-coded? Should I store it in a separate file and read it in? What is the most secure way to approach this? At the end of the day I am writing this application to learn and would very much like to learn to do it the correct way. Links to any relevant reading material would also be appreciated. I continue to google...

EDIT: So what would the potential drawbacks be if I stored program password as hash in a file. The user would have to know the password to use the application. Then let the program password that is protected by the hash be the encryption key to secure the sensitive information? Even if the source code and/or hash file is manipulated, the sensitive data would not be readable since the correct password is used as the key...what am I missing?

Comment: I'm assuming that your console application accesses some data that is stored in local files. In that case, your focus should be on encryption (and integrity) rather than authentication. Otherwise, what's to stop someone from bypassing your console application with its fancy authentication and accessing the files directly? It's like locking the door but leaving the window open. Encryption can be password-based, and some modes provide integrity checks so that you can detect alteration of your encrypted data too.

Comment: Also, hashing is good - but salt and hashing is better :)   Edit to add: Oh, I see Argon2 includes a salt - all good !

Comment: Thanks, erickson. You are correct in assuming the ultimate goal is to protect the data which I am storing in files. Part of this data will be sensitive data, which I am planning on encrypting. Some of this data will need to be decrypted and presented to the user. I guess my thinking was that by password protect the application, that would prevent someone from just launching it and reading the data from inside the program.

Comment: Ultimately you cannot solve this problem.  If your application runs on the users computer then the user controls everything your program does.  It would be relatively straight forward to extract and/or determine your encryption key.  If this is just for a toy program or something otherwise not-that-important, then your approach is probably fine.  If this needs *real* security - then this approach is not adequate by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Argon2 is a fine key derivation function for turning passwords into encryption keys.

However, if you are using the Argon2 hash as an encryption key, then don't store it on disk, obviously. If you store the encryption key next to the encrypted data you might as well not encrypt at all. One could even argue that it's worse, because it gives a false sense of security.

Properly encrypted data is useless without the key, so you don't have to protect the application itself. Just ask for the password if and when you need to encrypt or decrypt something. You can consider keeping the hash in memory for a while so you don't have to ask for it repeatedly, but don't persist it.

This is exactly how GPG works, for instance. It doesn't store any password hashes anywhere. Instead it stores private keys encrypted and just asks for the passphrase if it needs to decrypt a private key.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the feedback. I wasn't talking about using the hash as the key. I was talking about the password being the key. I guess my thinking was to allow the user to set the password on first run, and then access the program using that same password. The password would be validated against the hash, and all encryption will  use the password as the key. Having the hash would not allow you to decrypt the data, the user must supply the password.

Comment: Passwords are not suitable encryption keys. That's why key derivation functions exist. [User selected passwords have very low entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Human-generated_passwords), pretty much always south of 32 bits, and testing encryption keys is fast. This makes brute-force attacks very viable, and KDFs counter that by being intentionally slow. See [Key Stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).

Comment: And even if you did use the passwords directly (but really: don't), you wouldn't have to store it's hash. If it's entered correctly decryption will succeed, and otherwise it won't. The additional check against a stored hash doesn't do anything at all.